# "Unidentified character <" error when using Vue.js inside PyCharm

Tags: python, django, vue.js, pycharm, vuejs2

I am working on a Python Django project in which in one of the app, I have to do a lot of DOM manipulations. Earlier, I was using jQuery for this purpose but I want to use VueJS because of its virtual DOM. I am using PyCharm Pro. I am not able to use `.vue` files inside PyCharm. Somehow, I mistakenly set the '`language setting`' for `.vue` file to React RxJS (since Vue also supports RxJS). I then installed Vue plugin for PyCharm and restarted it. Still, I get the same error "`Unidentified character <`" in the template portion of Vue file. I found that VueJS is now supported with a plugin in PyCharm Pro (https://twitter.com/pycharm/status/848978918120058880).

Can someone tell me what I am missing? What changes in the project or PyCharm settings do I need to make?

**Edit**: If someone can, please provide any suggestions/alternative solutions to handle DOM manipulations other than jQuery.

Comment: Have you removed `*.vue` extension files from RxJS from `Editor > File Types`?

Comment: Is your problem simply the color which it displays as, or do you have issues with `Unidentified character`s? Is it possible to show a screenshot of what your problem is?

Comment: No. I can see `Vue.js templates` and `React JSX` in recognized file types list. However, registered patterns for Vue.js templates shows empty and `*.jsx` for React JSX. What should I change?

Comment: @nanotek The template of my .vue file has got background color yellow while the above Twitter link has got white background template. My issue is however the unidentified character. I am Ok with any color highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting `.vue` files in PyCharm to be recognized as HTML files.

I'm currently using PyCharm for a Flask / Vue.js project.

This is what my 'File Types' settings look like for `.vue` files:
[image]

And this is what a `.vue` file looks like in PyCharm for me:

[image]

When you attempt to add the `*.vue` pattern as an HTML file type, you should be forced by PyCharm to reassign it from the React JSX file type, so you shouldn't need to worry about manually removing the `*.vue` pattern from the React JSX file type.

Comment: This helped. One more doubt: in my .djhtml file, I am using v-on:click which gives error: 'Namespace v-on is not bound". How to fix this issue?

Comment: I've honestly never heard of `.djhtml` files before. I recommend creating a new StackOverflow question for that error.

Comment: Okay. But I figured it out somehow. I removed .djhtml file type association with HTML files. I am not getting syntax highlighting but atleast no errors though. .djhtml files are django templates, if I am correct.